NestJS and Swagger mongoDb ObjectId Type
I want to add ObjectId type as response
But the swagger change the ObjectId type as JSON object.
This is my Repsonse code:
@ApiOkResponse({
        description: 'The user ID',
        type: CreateUserResponseDto,
        isArray: false
    })

and the Dto Class
export class CreateUserResponseDto{
    @ApiProperty()
    userId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId
}

Do I can add ObjectId as type with the swagger?
Here is the swagger result



The Solution
export function ApiObjectIdProperty() {
    return applyDecorators(
        ApiProperty({
            type: String,
            example: '507f1f77bcf86cd799439011',
            description: 'MongoDB ObjectId',
        }),
    );
}
export class CreateUserResponseDto{
    @ApiObjectIdProperty()
    @IsString()
    userId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId
}


